# What is this? JS ERROR from gnome-shell keeps happening, and not finding answers

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I keep having this problem with GNOME Shell.  The errors below are logged into the journal (viewed with `journalctl -f`).  The only solution I've found is to log out of the GNOME session and start again.

Searching Google and this site produces lists of reports, but I cannot find any summary of (1) why does this happen? nor (2) What can be done to work-around or prevent the problem?

Also note that when it happens, UI responsiveness drops, often to the point of being barely usable.

```
JS ERROR: TypeError: windowActor is null _addWindowEffect@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/closeDialog.js:90:28 vfunc_show@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/closeDialog.js:162:14
```

P.S. Does JS mean Javascript, and if so, why is there Javascript in GNOME Shell?

--- update ---

Here is a pastebin of `grep -i gnome-shell /var/log/syslog*`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MmNnRVQrzG/

Output of `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`:

```
ls: cannot access '<snip>/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
```

Output of `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`:

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr 23  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Aug 18 06:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 15 22:12 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 29 11:57 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 29 11:58 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

--- another update ---
https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

[image: extensions.gnome.org screen shot]

Comment: Do `grep -i gnome-shell /var/log/syslog*` and paste the output at paste.ubuntu.com and give me the URL, and I'll take a look. Also edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: Working on that - I'm checking the grep output for potentially sensitive information...

Comment: There isn't any in the grep.

Comment: Yeah, I checked the grep output anyway - found it was clean.  `tr` and `sort -u` FTW.  I updated the question with the requested info.  Thank you for the help.  It would be awesome if I could learn to solve these myself.

Comment: Please redo the first `ls` command, as you appear to have not put in the leading `~`.

Comment: I did.  There is no extensions folder there.

Comment: Only `application_state  gnome-overrides-migrated` in the `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/` folder.

Comment: Are you fairly fluent in the `terminal`? Do you know how to restart gnome-shell?

Comment: I am very fluent in Linux, shell and more.  What is the best way to restart the shell? `kill -1`?

Comment: Show me a screenshot of https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

Comment: I put the screenshot in the question - I suspect this isn't what you wanted.  Shall I install the browser extension?

Comment: Yes, follow the instructions on the screen. You'll end up installing two pieces of software. Then revisit the web page and give me another screenshot.

Comment: Ahh, I remember how to restart gnome-shell via Alt-F2 as well.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to restart gnome-shell. Alt-F2 (or Alt-FN-F2), then r, then enter. Give me a few minutes to write an answer for you.

Comment: Screen shot updated.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Learning stuff**

Almost all gnome-shell errors are due to faulty gnome-shell extensions.

Good thing is that you don't have many of these extensions.

If you redo my `grep`, slightly modified, to:

```
grep -i gnome-shell /var/log/syslog* | grep -i extensions
```

You'll come up with a lot of hits that contain similar to this snippet:

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano
```

Guess which gnome-shell extension is suspect?

**Do the work**

So we'll move this extension out of the way and replace it with a substitute. I'll abbreviate my instructions, as you're `terminal` savvy.

cd /usr/share/gnome-shell

sudo mkdir extensions.HOLD

sudo mv extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano extensions.HOLD/desktop-icons@csoriano.OLD

restart gnome-shell

go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/ and install this extension.

restart gnome-shell

right-click on the Desktop and select "Settings" to set prefs.

Monitor system for gnome-shell errors AFTER the current time:

```
grep -i gnome-shell /var/log/syslog*
```

Comment: OK, I followed the instructions and will watch the syslog output.  Unfortunately, I don't know exactly what causes the errors to start, so I'll need to see if they come back.

Comment: @ash  If you revisit https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ you'll see the new extension. There's another extension that may be also causing problems, but we'll wait and see. Make sure that your system is updated via Software Updater.

Comment: This was very helpful.  I'll be more careful with extensions in the future.

Comment: I did refresh extensions.gnome.org/local and see the desktop-icons extension was removed.  Of course, my desktop icons are gone as well ;-).

Comment: @ash Desktop icons should be there. Can you right-click on the Desktop and see the Settings choice?

Comment: @ash Look at `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` again, and see if you find the new desktop-icons extension listed.

Comment: @ash You still there?

Comment: I'm back - stepped away for a little bit

Comment: So this is interesting - I closed a chrome window then re-opened it with CTRL-SHIFT-T, and I started getting more `JS ERROR: TypeError: actor.get_meta_window(...) is null`

Comment: @ash Next time that you step away, please tell me, as I sat here for quite some time waiting for you to respond. You didn't say what the `ls` commands show now. Does https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ properly show the new desktop-icons extension? Let's deal with the Chrome thing later.

Comment: No, the desktop icons extension is not there.  I'm not worried about it.  I appreciate your responsiveness, but I certainly don't expect it!  I'm stepping away again now.

Comment: @ash Go back to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/ and reinstall it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119203/discussion-between-heynnema-and-ash).

Comment: @ash If you have an update that you'd like to share, please don't add that info an existing answer. Either create a new answer, or put it into comments. Thanks!

Comment: makes sense - I'll add it as a separate answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Follow-Up**

Anyone finding this question and prior answer, I have an update that may help.

I later tracked the responsiveness problems down to notification spamming, so probably not related to the `windowActor is null` error.

Running "back in time" with a large number of file complaints (due to running out of disk space), it was sending a very large number of notifications, but "do-not-disturb" mode was enabled, so I didn't see them.  The notification spam overwhelmed the gnome shell.

The solution for the responsiveness problem was to fix the disk-space problem, and thus eliminate the source of notification spamming.